# Using Counters and Lists in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, character, counter

this is my program:

```
msg = input("What is your message? ")

print ()

num_alpha = 26
int_array = [0] * num_alpha

for alpha in range(num_alpha):
    int_array[alpha] = chr(alpha + 65)
    print(int_array[alpha], end = "")

print()

lett = 0
otherch = 0
num_vowels = 0
num_consanants = 0

count_character = [0] * 100000

length = len(msg)

for character in msg.upper():
    if character == "!":
        print("lett =", lett)
        print("other char = ", otherch)
        print("num_vowels = ", num_vowels)
        print("num_consanants = ", num_consanants)
    elif character < "A" or letter > "Z":
        otherch = otherch + 1
        count_character[ord(character)] = count_character[ord(character)] + 1
        print(count_character[ord(character)])
    else:
        lett = lett + 1
        count_character[ord(character)] = count_character[ord(character)] + 1
        print(count_character[ord(character)])

for character in msg:
        print("character", character, "appeared" , count_character[ord(character)] , "times")
```

i'm meant to be listing various features about the message (how many times each letter appeared, number of vowels, number of non-letter characters, etc.) but every time i print the last print statement it states that each character appeared 0 times.
any helpers?

EDIT: I've figured it out -

Because of the previous loop, rather than:

```
for character in msg:
    print("character", character, "appeared" , count_character[ord(character)] , "times")
```

The code needs to be:

```
for character in msg.upper():
    print("character", character, "appeared" , count_character[ord(character)] , "times")
```

Comment: the message is supposed to stop being read if a "!" appears

Comment: Looks like you are using upper case characters when you're counting them, but at the end you print out the counts of possibly lower case characters (you did not use msg.upper() in the second for loop).

Answer (score 0):

I think the or at least one problem is that you need to be careful if you use input() instead of raw_input()

The method input() is considered unsave, while raw_input realy reads in a string / character

```
>>> input()
a
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> raw_input()
a
'a'
>>>
```

also note:

```
>>> input()
"hello my name is tom"
'hello my name is tom'
>>> raw_input()
"hello my name is tom"
'"hello my name is tom"'
>>>
```

raw_input() recognices input always as string, whereas you have to enter quotation signs to let input() know that you want to input a string

Comment: He's using `print` functions which implies Python 3, which doesn't have the `input`/`raw_input` problem.

Comment: ah ok... sry. But print is also available in python 2.7